# Roads are looking blurry in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blur

I am trying to make some real looking roads in my game,but the problem is ,when i am using roads so they are little bit blurry at distance and look like a real one.Can any one please guide me to solve this.I have uploaded my pic here[image]

Is there possible solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a common problem, for textures' rendering at a certain distance/angle. You should enhance the [aniso level](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture-anisoLevel.html), in order to apply an anisotropic filtering on the blurry texture (you can also change the aniso level from the texture's component, as in the picture below).

[image]

If the road is created via a Terrain component (which I doubt, since you already have a sandy terrain at the bottom), you should change the [basemap distance](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Terrain-basemapDistance.html).

Comment: Roads are made by me and they 3ds models

Comment: Aniso level not working here....i want to make them look real...please any of you help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Check also Quality settings, it might have Anisotropic textures disabled.

[image: Edit/Project settings/Quality]

Comment: can you post screenshot of your texture importer settings and quality settings? (and which platform is selected)

Comment: Its android and can you suggest me some free assets that can help me to devlop rods easily