# Road texture is blurry when the camera is far away

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, shader, textures

How can I fix this issue ?If player nears the texture good quality but distance texture is bluryy.

- Disable Mip Map does not work,if i disabled generate mip map the texture shows ungainly
- Point (no filter), bilinear ,trilinear does not work
- Mip Bias does not work
- Diffuse Detail does not work
- Aniso Level does not work

My shader mobile/unlit Supports lightmap
İf I changed to standart shader or anyone does not work

My Tiling x=2 y=25
Offset x=0,y=0

Please help me.

[image]

For example, i disabled generate mip map , texture like this
[image]

Here is Inspector window about texture
[image]

Here is material window
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It is not about code okey but the problem is very common and there is no enough information about that.What is your advice?What can I do about that ?I don't know and i want to learn to solve this problem.

Comment: This is clearly a mipmapping problem send your texture settings, also send a picture where you disabled mipmap, i wonder what you mean by ungainly

Comment: There should be enough information in the question to reproduce the situation you are in so we can see exactly why "disable mip map does not work". Have you tried unchecking **Generate Mip Maps** in the texture importer?

Comment: Does Unity expose any settings around anisotropic filtering?

Comment: @Tommy yes, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252942/roads-are-looking-blurry-in-unity/33253045#33253045)

Comment: @Menyus i updated the topic.

Comment: @Latmos Your picture contains a different texture from a different angle, and texture settings is still missing update your post correctly please and read what Ruzihm linked

Comment: @Menyus I added.

Comment: Try leaving **Generate Mip Maps** off and enabling bilinear or trilinear filtering

Comment: @Latmos you still not provided a texture settings window, provide a pic like this https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/TextureImporter2019-1.jpg

Comment: @Menyus Finally I added.

Comment: I have the same issue, and still cant fix it 100% , the only way around is reducing the textures size from 2k to 1K and disable mipmaping, thats seems quite reduces this effect, but never found a clear solution about it.

If you found any solution plz provide it to us